# pymoo run multiobjective function

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

is it possible to run a ***3 objective, 16 constraints, 12 variable*** problem using ***pymoo on python***, and if there is other programs that could assist, please advise?
I have used pymoo code and it keeps providing this error.

```
File "C:\Users\omar.elfarouk\Anaconda3\lib\sitepackages\pymoo\model\problem.py", line 286, in evaluate

CV = Problem.calc_constraint_violation(out["G"])

KeyError: 'G'
```

the code is as ***following***

````
```#from pyomo.environ import *
from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.factory import get_problem
from pymoo.optimize import minimize
from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter
from pymoo.factory import get_termination
from pymoo.util import plotting
import autograd.numpy as anp
import numpy as np
from pymoo.util.misc import stack
from pymoo.model.problem import Problem
import numpy as np
import math```
````

## Define parameters

````
```#Factors for the third party in the supply chain%%
U_Demand = 12000#normrnd(mn,std)%Monte carlo simulation mean 12000 unit%
alpha = 0.1#Percentage of rate of return of products from third party%
lamda = alpha * U_Demand
miu =0.1#Probability of havieng a returned product in a good working condition% 
gamma=0.7#Probability of having a rerurned part after disassembly with good working condition%

Q_TP=(lamda*(miu))+(lamda*(1-miu)*gamma)#Quantity of the third party%

std  = 200 # 10000 runslamda and %
#for daikin australia
pd_1 = 600#round(random('Normal',600,24.49));q
pd_2 = 60#round(random('Normal',60,7.749));
Z_var = U_Demand - pd_1-pd_2 
#Transportation Costs#
TS_s = 5000  #Transportation cost for the supplier(From alexandria road to downtown cairo)%
TS_m = 5000  #Transportation cost for the manufacturer(Assumed to be almost fixed due to practicallity)%
TS_d = 5000  #Transportation cost for the distributer%
TS_rt = 5000 #Transportation cost for the retailer%
TS_tp = 5000 #Transportation cost for the third party%
#collection Costs%%
C_tp = 5.1 #collection cost of recovering used product from the customer%
#facility opening Costs%%
F_rt = 10000000 #facility opening cost for the recovery center(Assumed to be 10 million  Egyptian pound)%
#Ordering Costs%%
S_s = 5.1
S_ms = 58.956
S_m1 = 700
S_m2 = 800
S_m3 = 850
S_d = 173.4
S_r = 204
S_tp = 42.5
#Holding Costs%%
H_s = 50.126
H_ms = 589.56
H_m = 1473.9
H_dr = 1734
H_rt = 2040
H_tp = 425.9571
#Production Rates%%
P_m1=200 #Production Rates assumed to be 200 unit per day for the power plant %%
P_m2=210
P_m3=220
#U_Demand = 400000 #Demand rate is asumed to be 400,000 unit per month%
P_m = P_m1+P_m2+P_m3 # Production rate of the manufacuter
#i_m #conunting of manufacturer%
#i_mp    
#i_d   #Counting of Distributer
##Factors for the third party in the supply chain##
alpha = 0.1 #Percentage of rate of return of products from third party%
lamda =(alpha*U_Demand) 
miu =0.1  #Probability of havieng a returned product in a good working condition% 
gamma=0.7 #Probability of having a rerurned part after disassembly with good working condition%

Q_TP =(lamda*(miu))+(lamda*(1-miu)*gamma)     #Quantity of the third party%
#Values of supplied chain quantities
n_s = 5                                           
n_m = 1                                           #1:2
n_d = 1
````

Defining ***Pyomo problem and constraints***

````
class MyProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(n_var=12,
                         n_obj=3,
                         n_constr=16,
                         xl=anp.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]),
                         xu=anp.array([12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000,12800000000000]))
            def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs): #Defining the Objective and constrains#   
                Q_rt1 = x[:,0] # quantity of the retailer in the forward cycle
                Q_rt2 = x[:,1] # quantity of the retailer in the forward cycle
                Q_rt3 = x[:,2] # quantity of the retailer in the forward cycle
                Q_d1 = x[:,3] # Quantity of the distributer
                Q_d2 = x[:,4] # Quantity of the distributer
                Q_d3 = x[:,5] # Quantity of the distributer
                Q_m1 = x[:,6] # Quantity of the Manufacturer
                Q_m2 = x[:,7] # Quantity of the Manufacturer
                Q_m3 = x[:,8] # Quantity of the Manufacturer
                Q_s1 = x[:,9] #Quantity of Supplied Parts
                Q_s2 = x[:,10] #Quantity of Supplied Parts
                Q_s3 = x[:,11] #Quantity of Supplied Parts
                t_r= (U_Demand)/(x[:,0])   #Cycle time of the supply chain# #cycle time of the retailer
                t_d = n_d * t_r            #cycle time of the Distribiter
                t_m = (n_m * n_d* t_r)    #cycle time of the Manufacturer
                t_s =  n_s *n_m *n_d *t_r  #cycle time of the supplier
                t_tp = t_s                  #cycle time of the third party
                S_jfS=30   #Job Index factor number of fixed jobs at the supplier assumed to be 30 fixed employees %
                S_jfM=30   #Job index for the number of fixed jobs by Mamufacturer assumed to be 30 fixed employees %
                S_jfD=30   #Job index for the number of fixed jobs by distributer assumed to be 30 fixed employees%
                S_jfRT=30 #Job index for the number of fixed jobs by retialer assumed to be 30 fixed employees%
                S_jfTP=20 #Job index for the number of fixed jobs by third party recovery assumed to be 20 fixed employees%
                S_jvS=270 #Job Index factor number of variable jobs at the supplier assumed to be 270 workers per facility%
                S_jvM=270 #Job index for the number of variable jobs by Mamufacturer  270 workers per facility%
                S_jvD=270 #Job index for the number of variable jobs by distributer  270 workers per facility%
                S_jvRT=270#Job index for the number of variable jobs by retialer  270 workers per facility%
                S_jvTP=100#Job index for the number of variable jobs by third party recovery  100 workers per facility%
                S_u=20    #Employee satisfaction factor of the refurbrished parts for the third party disassembler%
                S_rt=30   #Customer satisfaction factor of the refurbrished parts%
                S_ds=5  #Number of lost days at work% # Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the suppliers / month%
                S_dm=5  #Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the manufactuer%
                S_dd=5  #Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the distributer%
                S_drt=5 #Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the retailer%
                S_dtp=5 #Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the third party%
                #Enviromental Aspect of the supply chain (Emissions calculated from carbon footprint)%
                E_q=10   #Emission factor from production line
                E_tp=10  #Emission from wastes removal%
                #Transportation emission cost%
                E_ts=20   #Emission from Transportation made by the supplier%
                E_tm=20   #Emission from Transportation made by the manufacturer%
                E_td=20   #Emission from Transportation made by the distributer%
                E_trt=20  #Emission from Transportation made by the retailer%
                E_ttp=20  #Emission from Transportation made by the third party 
                i_s = 1
                i_ss=np.arange(i_s,n_s+1,1)
                tc_s1= list(range(i_s,n_s+1))  
                for i_s in i_ss:
                    tc_s1 = np.sum(((i_ss)/n_s)*Q_s1*t_s)
                    i_s=i_s + 1  # Adding value of Supplier integer#
                tc_s4 = (tc_s1)

                TC_s1 =  (S_s*(1/(n_s*t_s)))+(((H_s+TS_s)/(n_s*(t_s)))*tc_s4) #cost of the supplier for component 1%

                i_s= 1    #starting of the loop#         
                i_ss=np.arange(i_s,n_s+1,1)
                #for w1 in w11:
                tc_s2= list(range(i_s,n_s+1))  
                for i_s in i_ss:
                    tc_s2=np.sum((i_ss/n_s)*Q_s2*t_s) #((x(11)) +Q_TP#
                    i_s = i_s + 1   #Adding value of Supplier integer 
                tc_s5 = (tc_s2)
                TC_s2 = (S_s*(1/(n_s*t_s)))+(((H_s+TS_s)/(n_s*(t_s)))*tc_s5)
                i_s=1    #starting of the loop#       
                tc_s3= list(range(i_s,n_s+1))  
                for i_s in i_ss:
                    tc_s3=np.sum((i_ss/n_s)*Q_s3*t_s)  #((x(12)+ Q_TP))%
                    i_s = i_s + 1   #Adding value of Supplier integer 
                tc_s6 = tc_s3
                TC_s3 = (S_s*(1/(n_s*t_s)))+(((H_s+TS_s)/(n_s*(t_s)))*tc_s6)                             
                i_m = 1    #starting of the loop#   
                i_mm=np.arange(i_m,n_m+1,1)
                #for w1 in w11:
                tc_m2= list(range(i_m,n_m+1))  
                for i_m in i_mm:
                    tc_m1 =np.arange(1,n_m,1) #Defining range with starting and ending point
                    tc_m2 = np.sum((1-((i_mm)/(n_m)))*((Q_m1)+Q_TP)) #Defining range with start & ending point#
                    i_m=i_m + 1  # Adding value of manufacturer integer#
                tc_m3=(tc_m2)        
                tc_s7 =np.arange(1,n_s,1) 
                #Total cost of manufacturer#
                tc_m = sum(tc_m1)
                tc_s8 = sum(tc_s7)
                TC_m =(H_m*((0.5*(Q_m1**2)*(1/P_m1))\
              +(tc_m*(Q_m1*t_m*(1/(n_m**2))))))\
              +((S_m1+TS_m)*(1/t_m))+((S_ms+TS_tp)*(1/t_s))\
              +(H_ms*(1/t_s)*(((((Q_s1+Q_TP)*Q_m1)/P_m1))\
              +(tc_s8*(((Q_s1)+Q_TP)/n_s)*(t_m-(Q_m1/P_m1)))))              

                TC_m2 =(H_m*((0.5*(Q_m2**2)*(1/P_m2))\
              +(tc_m*(Q_m2*t_m*(1/(n_m**2))))))\
              +((S_m2+TS_m)*(1/t_m))+((S_ms+TS_tp)*(1/t_s))\
              +(H_ms*(1/t_s)*(((((Q_s2+Q_TP)*Q_m2)/P_m2))\
              +(tc_s8*(((Q_s2)+Q_TP)/n_s)*(t_m-(Q_m2/P_m2)))))
                TC_m3 =(H_m*((0.5*(Q_m3**2)*(1/P_m3))\
              +(tc_m*(Q_m3*t_m*(1/(n_m**2))))))\
              +((S_m3+TS_m)*(1/t_m))+((S_ms+TS_tp)*(1/t_s))\
              +(H_ms*(1/t_s)*(((((Q_s3+Q_TP)*Q_m3)/P_m3))\
              +(tc_s8*(((Q_s3)+Q_TP)/n_s)*(t_m-(Q_m3/P_m3)))))

                i_d = 1
                i_dd=np.arange(i_d,n_d+1,1)
        #for w1 in w11:
                tc_d1= list(range(i_d,n_d+1))
                tc_d2= list(range(i_d,n_d+1))
                tc_d3= list(range(i_d,n_d+1))  
                for i_d in i_dd:
                    tc_d1=np.sum(((i_dd)/(n_d))*(Q_d1))    #Cost of the Distributer for Product 1%%
                    tc_d2=np.sum(((i_dd)/(n_d))*(Q_d2))   #Cost of the Distributer for Product 2%%
                    tc_d3=np.sum(((i_d)/(n_d))*(Q_d3)) #Cost of the Distributer for Product 3%%
                    i_d = i_d + 1

                tc_d_f = (tc_d1)+(tc_d2)+(tc_d3)
                TC_d = (H_dr*(tc_d_f/n_d))+((S_d+TS_d)*(1/t_d))  #Total cost of the distributer of the supply chain%
                #Total cost of retailer

                TC_rt = (H_rt*((Q_rt1)/2))+((S_r+TS_rt)*(1/t_r))  #Cost of the retailer%%
                TC_rt2 = (H_rt*(Q_rt2/2))+((S_r+TS_rt)*(1/t_r)) #Cost of the retailer for product 2%%
                TC_rt3 = (H_rt*((Q_rt3)/2))+((S_r+TS_rt)*(1/t_r)) #Cost of the retailer for product 3%%
                #Total cost of third party recovery 
                TC_tp = ((H_tp/2)*Q_TP)+((S_tp+TS_tp)*(1/t_tp))
                S_jfS=30   #Job Index factor number of fixed jobs at the supplier assumed to be 30 fixed employees %
                S_jfM=30   #Job index for the number of fixed jobs by Mamufacturer assumed to be 30 fixed employees %
                S_jfD=30   #Job index for the number of fixed jobs by distributer assumed to be 30 fixed employees%
                S_jfRT=30 #Job index for the number of fixed jobs by retialer assumed to be 30 fixed employees%
                S_jfTP=20 #Job index for the number of fixed jobs by third party recovery assumed to be 20 fixed employees%
                S_jvS=270 #Job Index factor number of variable jobs at the supplier assumed to be 270 workers per facility%
                S_jvM=270 #Job index for the number of variable jobs by Mamufacturer  270 workers per facility%
                S_jvD=270 #Job index for the number of variable jobs by distributer  270 workers per facility%
                S_jvRT=270#Job index for the number of variable jobs by retialer  270 workers per facility%
                S_jvTP=100#Job index for the number of variable jobs by third party recovery  100 workers per facility%
                S_u=20    #Employee satisfaction factor of the refurbrished parts for the third party disassembler%
                S_rt=30   #Customer satisfaction factor of the refurbrished parts%
                #Number of lost days at work%
                S_ds=5  # Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the suppliers / month%
                S_dm=5  #Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the manufactuer%
                S_dd=5  #Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the distributer%
                S_drt=5 #Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the retailer%
                S_dtp=5 #Number of lost days from injuries or work damage at the third party%
                #Enviromental Aspect of the supply chain (Emissions calculated from carbon footprint)%
                E_q=10   #Emission factor from production line
                E_tp=10  #Emission from wastes removal%
                #Transportation emission cost%
                E_ts=20   #Emission from Transportation made by the supplier%
                E_tm=20   #Emission from Transportation made by the manufacturer%
                E_td=20   #Emission from Transportation made by the distributer%
                E_trt=20  #Emission from Transportation made by the retailer%
                E_ttp=20  #Emission from Transportation made by the third party%
                #Cycle time%

                EQO = TC_s1+TC_s2+TC_s3+TC_m+TC_m2+TC_m3+TC_d+TC_rt\
                    +TC_rt2+TC_rt3+TC_tp
                    #       Economical aspect#
                LSC =(S_jfS+S_jfM+S_jfD+S_jfRT+S_jfTP)\
                    +((S_jvS*Q_s1)+(S_jvD*Q_d1)+(S_jvM*Q_m1)\
                    +(S_jvRT*Q_rt1)+(S_jvTP*Q_TP))\
                    +(S_u*(U_Demand))+(S_rt*Q_rt1)-(S_ds*Q_s1)\
                    +(S_dd*Q_d1)+(S_dm*Q_m1)+(S_drt*Q_rt1)\
                    +(S_dtp*Q_TP)#Social aspect equation%

                ESC=(E_q*(Q_s1+Q_d1+Q_m1+Q_rt1))\
                    +(E_ts*(1/t_s))+(E_td*(1/t_d))\
                    +(E_tm*(1/t_m))+(E_trt*(1/t_r))\
                    +(E_ts*(1/t_tp))+(E_tp*Q_TP)  #Enviromental aspect

                w1 = 1
                w2 = 1
                w3 = 1
                f1 = EQO*w1 
                f2 = LSC*w2
                f3 = ESC*w3

                g1 = -x[:,0]+U_Demand 
                g2 = -x[:,1]+U_Demand 
                g3 = -x[:,2]+U_Demand 
                g4 = -f1-f2-f3
                g5 = -((x[:,9])+Q_TP)+(n_s*x[:,6])
                g6 =-((x[:,10])+Q_TP)+(n_s*x[:,7])
                g7 =-((x[:,11])+Q_TP)+(n_s*x[:,8])
                g8 =(n_m*(x[:,3]))-x[:,6]
                g9 =(n_m*(x[:,4]))-x[:,7]
                g10 =  (n_m*(x[:,5]))-x[:,8]
                g11 = -x[:,3]+(n_d*x[:,0])
                g12 = -x[:,4]+ (n_d*x[:,1])
                g13 = -x[:,5]+ (n_d*x[:,2])
                g14 = -x[:,0]
                g15 = -x[:,1]
                g16 = -x[:,2]

                out["F"] = anp.column_stack([f1, f2, f3])
                out["G"] = anp.column_stack([g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10, g11, g12,\
                                      g13, g14, g15, g16]) 


problem = MyProblem()
```
````

Run ***Algorithm*** using ***NSGA***

````
```
#print(res)
from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
algorithm = NSGA2()

#from pymoo.factory import get_algorithm
algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=100)
termination = get_termination("f_tol", tol=0.001, n_last=20, n_max_gen=1000, nth_gen=10)

algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=100, eliminate_duplicates=True)

res = minimize(MyProblem(),
               algorithm,
               termination,
               seed=1,
               pf=problem.pareto_front(use_cache=False),
               save_history=True,
               verbose=True)
#res = minimize(objective,x0,algorithm,bounds=bnds,constraints=cons('n_gen', 200))
#minimize(objective,x0,method='COBYLA',bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)

plot = Scatter()
plot.add(problem.pareto_front(), plot_type="line", color="black", alpha=0.7)
plot.add(res.F, color="red")
plot.show()
```
````

is is possible to run the model using Pymoo optimization tool , or if there is another ***tool in Python*** that could support multiobjective ***(3 objective , 16 constraint and 12 variable type of problem)***

Comment: You may want to share your code if you want relevant feedback.

Comment: ```from pyomo.environ import ```
```from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2```
```from pymoo.factory import get_problem```
```from pymoo.optimize import minimize```
```from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter```
```from pymoo.factory import get_termination```
```from pymoo.util import plotting```
```import autograd.numpy as anp```
```import numpy as np```
```from pymoo.util.misc import stack```
```from pymoo.model.problem import Problem```
```import numpy as np```
```import math```

Comment: I'm getting the same error for a double objective problem using the same package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the main developer of pymoo.

I just had a look at your code. Please next time try to post a minimal example. It makes it much simpler for me and other to help you. Also, I would like to mention that **pyomo** and **pymoo** are two different frameworks.

The problem is not pymoo itself but how you define the `_evaluate` method. If you look carefully at your `__init__` method you can see that you are not overriding the `_evaluate` method but defining it in the constructor. 
If you delete the intend in your code for everything after the `def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):` line then your method is actually called (which is not the case right now).

Please look at our getting started guide to see how a problem is correctly defined:
https://pymoo.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Can you help me out with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280032/providing-constraints-in-pymoo-optimisation

Comment: @Julian, thanks for a great package! Are there any examples where you apply `pymoo` to a pandas dataframe rather than using the pymoo `problem` class?