# Providing constraints in Pymoo Optimisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have an objective function which looks like:

```
f1 = -1 * (constant1 * (variable1 - constant2))
```

And I have a constraint such that the function `f1` should only take values between 10 to 20 i.e.

```
10 <= f1 <= 20    where, f1 = -1 * (constant1 * (variable1 - constant2))
```

How do I code the above constraints in `pymoo` optimisation problem. I'm not interested in the bounds because as I see from the documentation, bounds are only for defining limits on the input(x) values and not for defining the limits on the output values of the objective function(f1) itself. I see that there are 2 ways to define a constraint:

1. Define the constraint directly inside the objective function itself
2. Define a `Repair` function and specify the constraints inside it

Can anyone guide me in framing the code for this constraint equation using `repair` or the default method? `repair` would be much more preferable since it seems flexible

I have gone through the documentation of pymoo, and this is all I am able to frame for the constraint equation:

```
g1 = f1-10
g2 = 20-f1
```

Comment: @Julian, Can you please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75775606/constructing-a-custom-problem-in-pymoo-picking-a-subset-of-vehicles-from-a-bag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would like to note that your objective function is a simple linear function which needs to be bounded in the design space to be bounded in the objective space. I assume your example is a proof of concept anyway. As you already stated in your question you have to define two constraints, one limiting `f1 < 20` and the other limiting `f1 > 10`. You do not need any `Repair` operator to achieve what you want to achieve. Also, having a boundary on an objective makes the repair very difficult in general. However, for your simple problem it would be also quite easy to implement (but would not really make sense generally speaking).

To achieve what you are intending to do you have to formulate the problem to be compliant with the pymoo definition.
In [pymoo](https://pymoo.org) the constraint violation is defined as follows: A solution is considered as *feasible* of all constraint violations are less than zero. A solution is considered as *infeasible* if at least one constraint violation is larger than zero. Therefore, the expressions above need to be correct (basically flipped). `g1 = 10 - f1` is less than zero (satisfied) when f1 is larger than 10.  `g2 = f1 - 20` is less than zero (satisfied) when f1 is less than 20.
A complete running code example looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np

from pymoo.algorithms.so_pattern_search import PatternSearch
from pymoo.model.problem import Problem
from pymoo.optimize import minimize


class MyProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self, const_1, const_2):
        super().__init__(n_var=1, n_obj=1, n_constr=2, xl=0, xu=100, type_var=np.double)
        self.const_1 = const_1
        self.const_2 = const_2

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        f = - (self.const_1 * (x[:, 0] - self.const_2))

        g1 = f - 20.0
        g2 = 10.0 - f
        G = np.column_stack([g1, g2])

        out["F"], out["G"] = f, G


problem = MyProblem(100.0, 1.0)

algorithm = PatternSearch()

res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               seed=1,
               verbose=False)

print("Best solution found: \nX = %s\nF = %s" % (res.X, res.F))
```

For this example, make sure you define `const_1` and `const_2` to be able to obtain an objective value in your defined range. Otherwise, the algorithm will not be able to find a feasible solution.

Moreover, I would like to mention that more details about implementing objective and constraint functions given a mathematical expression are explained in our [getting started guide](https://pymoo.org/getting_started.html).

Comment: @Julain. Thank You. I was able to find this same solution by the time I read this answer. Makes sense!

Comment: What if the value domain of f1 was something like this:
f1 -> [-5, 5] U [10, 20]
thanks in advance